# How can I uppercase my array as well as any word I push into that Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am working on an algorithm where you press a button and 2 checks happen:

- You can only push a word into array if that word doesn't exist in the array already and starts with the same letter that the last word in the array ends with.

I think i figured out the checks but i am trying to optimize it. If i type all lower case or all upper case it works, but if my word is "Maine"...the next word has to start with e and its "Egypt", it will not accept it, i need to lower case it to be accepted.

From what i understand one solution is to automatically convert all words in the Array to lower case or upper case and do the same to the word that is being added from field.value input.

For the life of me, i cannot implement it for some reason, iv been at it for 3 hours already and tried different tutorials. Not sure what i am doing wrong at this point.

Thank you for your time and explanation.

```
HTML

<div id="main-container">
    
    <input type="text" id="field" class="button">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <button class="button" id="play">Plasdfay</button>
    </div>
```

```
JS


const field = document.querySelector('#field');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play')

let usedCities = [];

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let fieldView = field.value;
    let lastWordInArray = usedCities[usedCities.length - 1]

    if(!usedCities[0] || !usedCities.includes(fieldView) && lastWordInArray[lastWordInArray.length - 1] === fieldView[0]) {
        usedCities.push(fieldView)

    }

    console.log(usedCities)
    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#field');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play')

let usedCities = [];

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let fieldView = field.value;
  let lastWordInArray = usedCities[usedCities.length - 1];

  if(!usedCities[0] || !usedCities.includes(fieldView) && lastWordInArray[lastWordInArray.length - 1] === (fieldView[0].toLowerCase() || fieldView[0].toUpperCase())) {
    usedCities.push(fieldView)
  }
  console.log(usedCities)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <div id="main-container">
    <input type="text" id="field" class="button">
    <button class="button" id="play">Play</button>
    <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just missed this check in your condition - `(fieldView[0].toLowerCase() || fieldView[0].toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 1):

If casing doesn't matter for checking, but you want to keep the casing in the array, you could do something like this:

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#field');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play')

let usedCities = [];

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let fieldView = field.value;
    let fieldViewLc = fieldView.toLowerCase();
    let checkUsedCities = usedCities.map(el => el.toLowerCase()); 
    let lastWordInArray = checkUsedCities[checkUsedCities.length - 1]
    
    if(!checkUsedCities[0] || !checkUsedCities.includes(fieldViewLc) && lastWordInArray[lastWordInArray.length - 1] === fieldViewLc[0]) {
        usedCities.push(fieldView)

    }

    console.log(usedCities)
    
})
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
    
    <input type="text" id="field" class="button">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <button class="button" id="play">Plasdfay</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much!! So, you converted field.value to lower case and you also converted usedCities array to lower case via MAP. You still push the word into array as it is typed but when you hit Play it converts the whole array to lower case and field.value,  before doing the check again.  Did i miss anything?

Comment: That is correct indeed! I keep the original values just for displaying in the array. Then on each button click you convert the array to lowercase through the map function and the field value is converted as well. Then you do the checks using the lowercase values but push the original values into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make lower case from last letter from last element of array and lower case from first letter from new word

```
const field = document.querySelector('#field');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play')

let usedCities = [];

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let fieldView = field.value;
    let lastWordInArray = usedCities[usedCities.length - 1]

    if(!usedCities[0] || !usedCities.includes(fieldView) && lastWordInArray[lastWordInArray.length - 1].toLowerCase() === fieldView[0].toLowerCase()) {
        usedCities.push(fieldView)

    }

    console.log(usedCities)
    
})
```

Comment: The issue doing it this way is, i can put same word "Egypt" and "egypt" which will add it into array twice.